# React-Bootstrap Popover with Form field Validation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I was trying to play off of the example code shown [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/155) in order to have an overlay trigger that displays a popover upon invalid username field regex for my form component. I'm getting the classic `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within "render"). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.` error upon trying to execute this code:

```
var UserField = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      value: ''
    };
  },

  getValue: function() {
    return this.refs.input.getValue();
  },

  validationState: function() {
    let valueCode = this.state.value;
    if (valueCode.length > 0) {
      switch (valueCode.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/)) {
        case null:
          this.refs.userHint.show();
          return 'warning';
          break;

        default:
          this.refs.userHint.hide();
          return '';
          break;
      }
    }
  },

  handleChange: function() {
    this.setState({
      value: this.refs.input.getValue()
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <OverlayTrigger
        ref="userHint"
        trigger="manual"
        placement="right"
        overlay={<Popover title='Invalid Username Format'>
                   <strong>Warning!</strong> Valid user credentials only contain alphanumeric characters, as well as heifens and underscores.
                 </Popover>
        }
      >
        <Input
          type = 'text'
          value = {this.state.value}
          label = 'Username'
          bsStyle = {this.validationState()}
          ref = 'input'
          groupClassName = 'input-group'
          className = 'form-control'
          onChange = {this.handleChange}
        />
      </OverlayTrigger>
    );
  }
});
```

Any help on this is very much appreciated, as always. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was developing this I would do it differently, with the `Input` managing it's own validation and exposing whether it's valid or not through its state (accessible through `refs`).

Without changing your approach, this should work better because it won't trigger changes in state of the parent component until the overlay has been shown or hidden:

```
validationState: function() {
  let valueCode = this.state.value;
  if (valueCode.length > 0) {
    switch (valueCode.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/)) {
      case null:
        return 'warning';
        break;

      default:
        return '';
        break;
    }
  }
},

handleChange: function() {
  let valueCode = this.refs.input.getValue();

  if (valueCode.length > 0) {
    switch (valueCode.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/)) {
      case null:
        this.refs.userHint.show();
        break;

      default:
        this.refs.userHint.hide();
        break;
    }
  }
  this.setState({
    value: valueCode
  });
},
```